# How to detect if Tabular variable is empty in KQL

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I have a dashboard populated with a number of Kusto KQL Queries.

Sometimes, my query below returns zero results (for instance if by miracle, there are no failures in the last 24 hours).

```
//my dashboard query 
let failureResults = exceptions | where blahblahblah;
failureResults;
```

When there are no items that match the filters, my dashboard is filled with

> 'The query returned no Results'.

How could I go about checking if this variable is null and then doing a different op?  For instance, if it's null, then I would just issue a `print "No Failures for today, awesome!";` instead.

I have tried `iff()` statements and `isempty(failures| distinct Outcome)` and the like, but to no avail. For example, here is another one which didn't work:

```
failures | project column_ifexists(tostring(Outcome),"No failures where reported!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought on an improved solution based on [pack_all()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packallfunction) and the [bag_unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin) plugin

```
let p_threshold = ... ;// set value
let failureResults = datatable(exception_id:int,exception_val:int,exception_text:string)[1,100,"Hello" ,2,200,"World"];
failureResults
| where exception_val > p_threshold
| as t1
| project result = pack_all()
| union kind=outer (print msg = 'No Failures for today, awesome!' | where toscalar(t1 | take 1 | count) == 0 | project result = pack_all())
| evaluate bag_unpack(result)
```

let p_threshold = 0;

| exception_id | exception_text | exception_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 100 |
| 2 | World | 200 |

let p_threshold = 300;

| msg |
| --- |
| No Failures for today, awesome! |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QMU/DMBCF9/yKI0sTKVKTjq3CiJgYWBgQiq7xNQm52pF9pkXix3OmQlAG5MHnd%20/5Ph2TwNLJ6CmMjg20UMNuvYag%20htypIy1OuDE0dMjhcgS1GRQ9OyZCjr3tMjkbDeZ7WSl%20hE0/0cROss2iJ/sUD43VVPXVX5PzC6HalNt0vPJeTb5yy67npl9wGkkT3D1Pdz%20hlcPBpBG78W7V%20oF/FdagRfs5w6Zi1K70Woe5sma1kUhD8WiSALHMKh19eDg7jI8wMF5EGfwvQI8UXBHulnBN4u40COjL6RRTXAmSEXvopUS2rTLf1ESC6UtoxDsceiiTc3iYi0/AYbbiEWcAQAA)

Answer (score 3):

Well... Kind of...

```
let p_threshold = ... ;// set value
let failureResults = datatable(exception_id:int,exception_val:int,exception_text:string)[1,100,"Hello" ,2,200,"World"];
failureResults
| where exception_val > p_threshold
| as t1
| union kind=outer (print msg = 'No Failures for today, awesome!' | where toscalar(t1 | take 1 | count) == 0)
| project-reorder msg
```

let p_threshold = 0;

| msg | exception_id | exception_val | exception_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 100 | Hello |
|  | 2 | 200 | World |

let p_threshold = 300;

| msg | exception_id | exception_val | exception_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No Failures for today, awesome! |  |  |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA13QwU7DMAwG4PukvYPpZa0UpHbHoXJEnDhw4YDQFBpvDfPiynHYkHh4XCEEQ7k4vy19iQkVpq2OgnlkCtBDe7NckKU7H6kIPmIupNkawaudV8IazwNOGjltY9jEpO43ePf0L1E86yarxLRvnjvXta2r7pGIK3Brt56vTywUqheDL9Hl4hNOIwrCBQC3f588D/kM2s1FSTYDh5hCz0VRoJ4MVjjmvf1g9cBw9y1k2LGAcvAfDvwJMx/xagU/nnIePHmptbNM/QFhLgYuSRvobUvNzE3CbzjotSBLMM2YLy6WXL5RAQAA)

Comment: This works for me!  Thank you!